# Find the differences between 2 result sets using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a help to count the differences between two result sets.

The dataset is looking like :

Table 1: `submissions`

```
SubmissionID | TransID | Code
-------------------------------
s1              u1      code1
s1              u2      code2
s1              u3      code3
s2              u4      code1
s2              u5      code3
s3              u6      code1
```

Table 2 : `resubmissions`

```
resubmissionID | SubmissionID | TransID | Code
-----------------------------------------------
s11             s1              u1      changed1
s11             s1              u2      changed2
s22             s2              u4      changed1
s22             s2              u5      code3
s33             s3              u6      code1
```

The expected results is to count the `TransID` with changed code, please note that it may contains not changed code, and I'm using SQL Server 2008

currently I wrote a query to joins this 2 tables :

```
select * from 
submissions s inner join resubmissions r
on s.submissionid = r.resubmissionid
and s.TransID = r.TransID 
and s.code <> r.code
```

and we can use case to check if the code changed or not, but it is show me redundant values

```
submissionid    claimcode   type    code        ResubmissionID  submissionid    claimcode   type    code
7863            OCR         S       E86.0   18697           7863            OCR         P       K52.9
7863            OCR         P       K52.9   18697           7863            OCR         S       E86.0
```

Please advice

Regards,

Comment: Show us **your efforts so far!** This is not a *write the code for me* service - we'll gladly help if you have something and you're stuck....

Comment: Change that to `on s.submissionid = r.submissionid`

Comment: it is not working in the real data it is show results twisted (see the updates) while this two rows not changed

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

SELECT TransID
FROM submissions
WHERE Code <> (SELECT Code FROM resubmissions WHERE submissions.TransID  = resubmissions.TransID  )

Note: This query lists all TransID with changed codes only. (ie u1,u2, and u4)